# Split string to get a part of it

Tags: php, string

I have this string from a database:

```
<href="/supplier/plant-whole-payment-details/80912">22441769</a>
```

I only need **80912**. How can I get it in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<href="/supplier/plant-whole-payment-details/80912">22441769</a>';

preg_match('/href=".*\/(?P<digit>\d+)"/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches['digit'];
```

Comment: @user2114575 :  welcome :), once you find this answer useful accept it (click the tick mark), some people may find that useful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to *split* the string, but extract a part of it. Regular expressions come in handy for that. If the string is always similar to the one in your example, use this one to get the first match of digits between `/` and `"`:

```
$string = '<href="/supplier/plant-whole-payment-details/80912">22441769</a>';
preg_match('#/(\d+)"#', $string, $matches);
$value = $matches[1];
```

**Further explanation:**

- `\d` stands for "digit"
- `+` stands for "one or more"
- `#` is a delimiter that marks start and end of the pattern
- the parantheses mark a subpattern, that will be added to the `$matches` array

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with `substr` . check this code  .

```
<?php
// your text which needs to be splited .
 $text = "/supplier/plant-whole-payment-details/80912" ;

 $reqText = substr($text , -5);

?>
```

this will output the number .at the end of the string .

Comment: Better: first check the string in the question, then give an answer ;) Also, you assume that the number always has the same length.

Comment: @fab : check the question . is it written anywhere that string will be of different length ? also is he saving a whole anchor tag in the database . See the irony :)

Comment: I won't argue for the quality of the question and the underlying design ;) But your code would in fact return `9</a>` - you get the point?

Comment: I know that why i said it .is he saving a whole anchor tag in the database ?

Answer (score -3):

Use this...

In this example we will break a string to an array:

```
<?php
 $str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
 print_r (explode(" ",$str));
 ?>
```